# Unable to position the elements while swapping inside a modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've two draggable divs inside a modal popup, when I drag and drop,the positions of divs are coming down during the animation period.I am unable to sort it out.

**HTML**

```
<title>
  Swapping of tiles with Animation</title>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          <div class='droppable'>
            <div class="draggable">Draggable 1</div>
          </div>
          <div class='droppable'>
            <div class="draggable">Draggable 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.startPos = window.endPos = {};

  makeDraggable();

  $('.droppable').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hoverClass',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $from = $(ui.draggable),
        $fromParent = $from.parent(),
        $to = $(this).children(),
        $toParent = $(this);

      window.endPos = $to.offset();

      swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 200);
      swap($to, window.endPos, window.startPos, 1000, function() {
        $toParent.html($from.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
        $fromParent.html($to.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
        makeDraggable();
      });
    }
  });

  function makeDraggable() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
      zIndex: 99999,
      revert: 'invalid',
      start: function(event, ui) {
        window.startPos = $(this).offset();
      }
    });
  }

  function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
    $el.css('position', 'absolute')
      .css(fromPos)
      .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
        if (callback) callback();
      });
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/te4anpgr/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) instead of [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) when you have changed the `position` value of an element to `absolute` and you want to position it in the same location.

Since you change the element's `position` to `absolute`, you are dealing with a [*positioned element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) (i.e., "an element whose computed position property is either `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky`"). When you set the [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) css property of a positioned element, you are specifying "the distance between the top margin edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block" (not the top edge of the document). The containing block is the closest ancestor that is also a positioned element. JQuery refers to the containing block as the ***[offset parent](https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/)***.

While the [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function gets the coordinates of the element "relative to the document", the [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) function gets the coordinates "relative to the offset parent".

The offset parent for the element you are animating is the element with the class "modal-body". (It is the closest ancestor that is a positioned element. It has a `position` value of `relative`.) You don't really need to determine the offset parent though, since the [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) function will determine it for you.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8z19fouc/)

This jsfiddle is identical to the original, except each call to `.offset()` has been replaced with a call to `.position()`.

Comment: Its working perfectly, I checked in IE11 browser too

Comment: A little bit of visual improvement, at least for Chrome and FF, could be adding the property `cursor: grab` and `cursor: grabbing` to let the user know it's a draggable element. [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/6yb35pc2/)

Comment: @John S Thanks and sorry for very late reply

Comment: @RicardoRuiz fantastic improvement. Thanks, I am using it.

Answer (score 0):

Change position from absolute to fixed.

```
function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
  $el.css('position', 'fixed')
  .css(fromPos)
  .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
    if (callback) callback();
  });
 }
```

Comment: Still not swapping perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for or not but this is an option(albeit a hacky one).

I tried understanding the root cause of the problem but could not do so, hence thought of a hacky solution to the problem.
change your function swap with this.

```
 function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {

$el.css('position', 'fixed')
  .css(fromPos)
  .css('margin-top','-10px')
  .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
    if (callback) callback();       
    $el.css('margin-top','0px');
  });
```

}

Another suggestion, increase the animation duration in the first phase. 
something like this `swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 1000);`